# Passing variable/array into WordPress the_content()

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm looking to pass an array from a separate database within wordpress and echo it out into the content, having a bit of trouble understanding how.

Here is my current code in functions.php:

```
function get_lead() {
    $wpdb = new wpdb('root','password','database', 'localhost');
    if ($wpdb->connect_errno) { 
        die("Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $db->connect_errno . ") " . $db->connect_error);
    }

    // Get lead info
    if(isset($_SESSION['lead_id'])) {
        global $lead;
        $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'customers';
        $lead = $wpdb->get_row($wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM $table_name WHERE id = '".$_SESSION['lead_id']."'", ARRAY_A));
        $error = $wpdb->print_error();  

        return $lead;
    }   
}
```

I originally tried this in a custom php file included in a custom wordpress header via require_once 'filename.php';, here is the code for that:

```html
if(isset($_SESSION['lead_id'])) {
 $lead_query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM customers WHERE id = '".$_SESSION['lead_id']."'");
 $lead = $lead_query->fetch_assoc();
 $lead_query->free();
}
```

I know this gets the data fine and passing the variable if I place it in header.php and echo out there, but I can't get WordPress to load it into the content within the editor, it's just an empty if I echo $lead['postcode']; there for example.

I've tried setting up a shortcode but can't seem to return an array with that, and the function action doesn't seem to work either, I just get NULL when I var_dump($lead);

It's a 3 step form with a thank you page at the end. I want to echo one piece of data into the first step of the form and two pieces of data onto the thank you page.

Hope this makes sense, any help would be great :)

Comment: `a separate database within wordpress` - > does your table name use the wp table prefix then?  (i.e. is `$wpdb->prefix` necessary?

Comment: Nope it doesn't, but if I put the code above in header.php and var_dump($lead); it spits out an array.

Comment: Ok, what's in the array?  That's better than NULL

Comment: Here is a copy paste of the first bit (too long otherwise): 

object(stdClass)#339 (23) { ["id"]=> string(2) "63" ["name"]=> string(4) "test" ["email"]=> string(15) "test@test.co.uk" ["telephone_a"]=> string(10) "2131231232"

It's all the info I need, just can't pass it into the actual content within the page edit area of wordpress.

Comment: Why not?  Why can't you return $lead, and use it wherever you need it?  Maybe I don't understand what you're trying to do, but the code posted in the question is evidently returning data correctly.

Comment: Ok sorry maybe I'm not explaining very well, here we go:

I load a custom header.php file on the pages step-1, step-2, step-3 and thank-you pages.

In the header I add a file via require_once(filename.php);.

In that file I have all the code to handle dealing with the form data, this all works absolutely fine, for example saves the data into a sql database.

Now I want to then call on the data and load it onto the page, but for some reason I can't do that within the wordpress editor if where to simple echo it out like so:

`<input value="<?php echo $lead['postcode']; ?>" />`

Comment: The `var_dump()` tells you this is an object of type stdClass, so you can't echo it out like that.  You need to use `->` syntax to access the data inside.  Try `echo $lead[0]->postcode;`